# Correct php syntax to add an image in wp functions.php

Tags: functions

I am trying to add a function in WordPress `functions.php` where i want to display an image relevant to my theme folder

here is my code which is not working, it only shows the file name but without the correct path.

```
add_filter (somefilter_code_here);
function mycustom_func($mycustom_field ) {
$capimg =  bloginfo('template_url').'/imagename.jpg'; 
echo $capimg; // for  testing and it does work
$mycustom_field .= '<p class="custom_image">';
//$comment_field .= '<img scr="'. $capimg' . '" alt="custom_image"/>';
$mycustom_field .= '<img scr="'. bloginfo('template_url').'/imagename.jpg'   . '"    alt="captcha"/>';  
$mycustom_field .= "</p>";
return $comment_field;
}
```

i need an exact php line which can retrieve image from path and display it

right now image is not displayed, it show only file name and the value of $capimage is shown separately

Answer (score 0):

do use [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) when working with strings;

example:

```
$capimg =  get_bloginfo('template_url').'/imagename.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your current template's directory, use `get_template_directory_uri()`, so the above code should be:

```
add_filter (somefilter_code_here);
function mycustom_func($mycustom_field ) {
$capimg =  get_template_directory_uri().'/imagename.jpg'; 
echo $capimg; // for  testing and it does work
$mycustom_field .= '<p class="custom_image">';
//$comment_field .= '<img src="'. $capimg' . '" alt="custom_image"/>';
$mycustom_field .= '<img src="'. $capimg . '" alt="captcha"/>';  
$mycustom_field .= "</p>";
return $comment_field;
}
```

Also, use `src` instead of `scr` to output the image.